# Bidirectional tree graph chart in Sencha Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, graph, charts, tree

Hi guys how do I create a tree graph in ext is. Any pointers to snippets or approaches or ready to use js plugins?

It will look similar to the diagram in below link. But should be able to display information like

- bidirectional
- weight between each nodes
- name n each node
- should support many to many connections

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/memory-profiling-files/dominatorsspanning.png

Any suggestions or links.